# [Typescript]: How to type a generic function to accept a more specific object as argument?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I want to pass a selector to a child component via selector property. The selector property is a generic function which accepts a single object and returns a value. See example below ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCoHoa4BlXJOAZ1DABsXWYUYkVGAE8wLBnwFwAvHADeVOHACurJFABc8xUrgA7FCCRbeUYHoDmAGh1LWyqAaMmYZyzcpKAvlS8VqlHSMzGwc3GxI3BjQVGgQerxwFkgwAKpqUAByhiyyABS8-MaMkkgAlDIAfGylAHSq6rVOSP5CouKRSNFQMnAAPAgQEDASRb3IcVAAJn2m5tYqegDWehAA7nqVVoydGEhTvcrLqxuVBaVag8OjAhXS1Qy7AlNUtPTI6PAAwriQekh6eAABRwYlgwCQrDaYjgIIgYJgENYvQUngiURg0C0jwx0H8flegXoP3A8QBMFi8USJL+5N6eTAoNYWjhCKRd2qqKUcQS8Dk6K6mJ6Xl6jPhrFaaJoACppXAACIQNjMGAAC3mcDWwDVcDVPCe0Dg0pohKURBgDj0+mUnE4+MlQSBKCIgLgcVJ-1dYBQrHYljgKAF3V1SrQ6s4L0oPMSAEEwGB6RztETdAAVdoEc5FbGlJNzSz4ODAZGreA+9gWAwAI3CmN1GfwAyGI1KKK82xxgv2h2O602WYEl2bN3KVR2GP2+FqbzT7WREEwcG9UByAigyPwhQEhZQegOm9KO6IRb07u9iJrSGnKd0cHTMPwVxbRULxf0wwDvuAlZQl5D9YfEcpzyAAmABmECQLKGdzDAZQYFqGBWAADzyABGAA2bYwLKLRU1VFgkGQsQ9gOEQYXdSE4GwXAl1BdQRAINRcSgQs1nVMMi2RKYuk4Z1uwI494gAlh8AASUBNx2DQGMYFcYAq3gqiADJYXo8FIXwHRzUtfoaTJV1mMFaBpDkZI0gybIjBFGhKl8fwgA)).

```
import React from 'react';

// Some simple state
type State = {
  user: {
    name: string,
    surname: string,
  }
};

// Some simple selector
const getUserName = (state: State) => state.user.name;

type Selector = <RootState = Record<string, unknown>, Selected = unknown>(state: RootState) => Selected;

// React Component Properties
type Properties = {
  selector: Selector;
};

// Component
const Component = (props: Properties) => {
  const { selector } = props;

  /** Do something with the selector */

  return null;
};

// Parent component passing a selector to child
const App = () => {
//   Type '(state: State) => string' is not assignable to type '<RootState = {}, Selected = unknown>(state: RootState) => Selected'.
//   Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
//     Type 'RootState' is not assignable to type 'State'.(2322)
// input.tsx(16, 3): The expected type comes from property 'selector' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Properties'
  return <Component selector={getUserName} />
};
```

It fails to assign an object with specific properties into an object which accepts any properties. Why is that? I encountered this in a different situation and couldn't find a workaround.

(Obviously, I am trying to understand the issue and simply turning these warnings off is not a desired solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the component generic:

```
// React Component Properties
type Properties<RootState extends Record<string, unknown>, Selected> = {
  selector: (state: RootState) => Selected;
};

// Component
function Component<RootState extends Record<string, unknown>, Selected>(props: Properties<RootState, Selected>) {
  const { selector } = props;

  /** Do something with the selector */

  return null;
}

// Parent component passing a selector to child
const App = () => {
  return <Component selector={getUserName} />
};
```

Comment: This doesn't complain about anything. Which is good. But any idea why it complained in my case? Can't a property of the object be a generic function?

Comment: The type information needs to be passed all the way through the object, if that makes sense.